# netbeans c++ style comments in c source

Tags: netbeans

is there any way to have a shortcut / macro to put c++ (double slash) style comments
in C sources ? I only menage to obtain c (no-block) comments ie.

```
/*
 comment...
*/
```

which is somewhat umcomfortable

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your compiler and if 'strict' is applied.

> C99 introduced several new features, (..) and support for one-line
>   comments beginning with //, as in BCPL or C++. Many of these had
>   already been implemented as extensions in several C compilers.

Comment: it's supported as my compiler is gcc and i use std99